# JQuery venn diagram click function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have written the following function within the success of another ajax call :
I have used the readymade jquery and rapheal function for the venn diagram and used both there js ,here's the code :

```
            ( function($) { 
          $(function() {
            $('#venn-demo').venn({ numSets: 3, 
                universeLabel : 'All rate centers '
            });
            $('.new-venn').click(function() {
              $('#venn-demo').html('').venn({ 
                  numSets : $(this).attr('data-num-sets') 
                  });
              $('#region-list').html('');
            });
            $('#venn-demo').on('regionClicked.venn', function(e) {
              var activeRegions = $('#venn-demo').venn('activeRegions')
                , arNames = []
                ;

              for ( var i in activeRegions ) {
                arNames.push( activeRegions[i].getId() == "" ? "U" : activeRegions[i].getId() );
              }

              $('#region-list').html( arNames.join(', ') );
            });
          });
        })(jQuery);
```

The resulting venn diagram should be clickable but it is not, also I am getting this error:
e.attr is not a function

How should I make this work?

Answer (score 0):

**Use this code for click function in venn diagram :**

Download : http://www.filedropper.com/vennchart

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Venn</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="./css/main.css" />
    <!-- Le HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML5 elements -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
         <script src="//html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery.ba-hashchange.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/main.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/raphael-min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery.venn.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="vennLoad()">

  <div id="venn-demo" style="margin: 0 auto; width: 430px; height: 300px"></div>

  <div style="text-align: center;">Active Regions: <span id="region-list"></span></div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    ( function($) {

      $(function() {

        $('#venn-demo').on('regionClicked.venn', function(e) {
          var activeRegions = $('#venn-demo').venn('activeRegions'), arNames = [];

          for ( var i in activeRegions ) {
            arNames.push( activeRegions[i].getId() == "" ? "U" : activeRegions[i].getId() );
                        console.log(arNames);
          }
          $('#region-list').html( arNames.join(', ') );
          $('#venn-demo').find("svg").remove();
          var regionVal = $('#region-list').text();
          vennLoad(regionVal);
        });

      });
    })(jQuery);

        function vennLoad(regionVal){

            $('#venn-demo').venn({ numSets: 3, setLabels:['AA: 60 ', 'BB: 70', 'CC: 30'] });

        }
  </script>

  </body>
</html>
```